# logback is ignoring my logback.xml

Tags: scala, logging, logback

I have a sbt/scala project that includes as on of its dependencies "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.13" and includes a logback.xml file whose contents are here:

```
<configuration debug="true">
    <logger name="com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.ConfigSSLContextBuilder" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.AlgorithmChecker" level="ERROR"/>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                <pattern>%d{ISO8601} | %-5level | %thread | %logger{1} | %m%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    </root>
</configuration>

https://pastebin.com/S1qauMi9
```

When I run the program, I get the output here:

```
[WARN] [07/05/2017 16:01:25.782] [main] [com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.ConfigSSLContextBuilder] validateStore: Skipping certificate with weak key size in thawtepremiumserverca: Certificate failed: cert = "1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#16197072656d69756d2d736572766572407468617774652e636f6d,CN=Thawte Premium Server CA,OU=Certification Services Division,O=Thawte Consulting cc,L=Cape Town,ST=Western Cape,C=ZA" failed on constraint RSA keySize < 2048, algorithm = RSA, keySize = 1024
[WARN] [07/05/2017 16:01:25.782] [main] [com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.ConfigSSLContextBuilder] validateStore: Skipping certificate with weak key size in thawteserverca: Certificate failed: cert = "1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#16177365727665722d6365727473407468617774652e636f6d,CN=Thawte Server CA,OU=Certification Services Division,O=Thawte Consulting cc,L=Cape Town,ST=Western Cape,C=ZA" failed on constraint RSA keySize < 2048, algorithm = RSA, keySize = 1024
```

...

```
16:01:25,822 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
16:01:25,822 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
16:01:25,822 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/Users/eswenson/Projects/Modulus/ws/modulus-shared-libraries/modules/dataset-client-cli/target/scala-2.11/dataset-client-cli-assembly-1.0.dev.jar!/logback.xml]
16:01:25,833 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@1eaf1e62 - URL [jar:file:/Users/eswenson/Projects/Modulus/ws/modulus-shared-libraries/modules/dataset-client-cli/target/scala-2.11/dataset-client-cli-assembly-1.0.dev.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
16:01:25,873 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.ConfigSSLContextBuilder] to ERROR
16:01:25,873 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.AlgorithmChecker] to ERROR
16:01:25,873 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to ERROR
16:01:25,907 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
16:01:25,908 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@6fd1660 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
[WARN] [07/05/2017 16:01:26.084] [main] [com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.ConfigSSLContextBuilder] validateStore: Skipping certificate with weak key size in thawtepremiumserverca: Certificate failed: cert = "1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#16197072656d69756d2d736572766572407468617774652e636f6d,CN=Thawte Premium Server CA,OU=Certification Services Division,O=Thawte Consulting cc,L=Cape Town,ST=Western Cape,C=ZA" failed on constraint RSA keySize < 2048, algorithm = RSA, keySize = 1024
[WARN] [07/05/2017 16:01:26.085] [main] [com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.ConfigSSLContextBuilder] validateStore: Skipping certificate with weak key size in thawteserverca: Certificate failed: cert = "1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#16177365727665722d6365727473407468617774652e636f6d,CN=Thawte Server CA,OU=Certification Services Division,O=Thawte Consulting cc,L=Cape Town,ST=Western Cape,C=ZA" failed on constraint RSA keySize < 2048, algorithm = RSA, keySize = 1024

Full log here:  https://pastebin.com/6Xd10TZZ
```

Two issues:

1) why is there java logging output BEFORE logback appears to be getting configured?  How can I make sure that logback is initialized first?

2) why are all those warnings from com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.ConfigSSLContextBuilder logged, when I explicitly set the level for these to be ERROR?

I've enabled logback configuration debugging so that you can see that logback does claim to be setting the loglevel to ERROR for this class.  But still the messages are logged.

Answer (score 0):

The only tag allowed inside the root-tag is appender-ref, where you reference a previously defined appender via name[1]. Move your appender definition to the start of your configuration and only reference it inside the root. Also, if your understanding of logback configuration is this basic you should first change that by reading the manual[2].

[1] https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#rootElement

[2] https://logback.qos.ch/manual/index.html

Comment: Changing to this, doesn't help.  Still has exact same behavior:
https://pastebin.com/2nGkB934

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be the fact (I still don't understand why this is true), that the following akka configuration logic:

```
akka {
  loglevel = "ERROR"
  stdout-loglevel = "ERROR"
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
}
```

which was included in a reference.conf in a library used by the CLI utility needed to get added to a not-yet-existing application.conf in the CLI JAR.  While I don't understand why this was necessary, it caused the issue to go away.  I had thought that including a reference.conf in a library resulted, if not overridden by corresponding config in a caller of the library, would still take effect.  Clearly, I was wrong.